# Copying files with limitation of 100MB

Tags: c#

Help to finalize the make up of all files and folders, and copy them to a folder, you need to do to limit the folder to 100MB

How to make a constant check of the folders on the volume 100MB, if the limit of files in a folder is exceeded, to complete the copying.

```
public static void GetFilesList()
{
    long DS = 1000000;
    string[] extens = 
    { 
    ".txt", ".doc", 
    ".cs", ".ico", 
    ".Dll", ".Html", 
    ".Htm", ".Xml", 
    ".Php", ".png", 
    ".jpg", ".gif" 
    };
    if (DirSize(new DirectoryInfo(Easy.GooVer), DS) > DS)
    {
        foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(Easy.GooVer, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            if (Array.IndexOf(extens, ext) >= 0)
            { try{
              File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(Easy.str1, Path.GetFileName(fileName)), true);}catch { }
            }
        }
    }
}
public static long DirSize(DirectoryInfo d, long aLimit = 0)
{
    long Size = 0;
    FileInfo[] fis = d.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
    {
        Size += fi.Length;
        if (aLimit > 0 && Size > aLimit)
            return Size;
    }
    DirectoryInfo[] dis = d.GetDirectories();
    foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dis)
    {
        Size += DirSize(di, aLimit);
        if (aLimit > 0 && Size > aLimit)
            return Size;
    }
    return (Size);
}
```

P.S: I'm using .Net 2.0 and I don't want to use Linq.

Comment: Surely you would move your call to DirSize to inside of the loop? though not sure precisely what you're asking..almost feels like a homework question

Comment: DirSize I assign GetFilesList, Tried adding `while(true)` but did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive code is not correct.

You can use a simpler code to get the directory size

```
public static long DirSize(DirectoryInfo d)
{
    return d.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(f => f.Length);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't, in any way, address his issue though. He needs to check before each copy.

Comment: @ArteS Posting an answer was a mistake from me... I'll leave it to you to convert to a non-linq code..

Comment: @L.B, How to use your DirSize in this example? 
What check should I do in `if ()`?